# How to pass variables to annotations or yaml?

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony we can:

```
     /**
     * @Route(
     *     "/articles/{_locale}/{year}/{slug}.{_format}",
     *     defaults={"_format": "html"},
     *     requirements={
     *         "_locale": "en|fr",
     *         "_format": "html|rss",
     *         "year": "\d+"
     *     }
     * )
     */
    public function show($_locale, $year, $slug)
    {
    }
```

And:

```
article_show:
  path:     /articles/{_locale}/{year}/{slug}.{_format}
  controller: App\Controller\ArticleController::show
  defaults:
      _format: html
  requirements:
      _locale:  en|fr
      _format:  html|rss
      year:     \d+
```

My question is mainly about languages.

Can I pass en|fr from parameters.yml or from PHP (for example I have definied languages in database) to annotations and yaml?

Now this is the duplication of the code and in addition if the client adds a new language to the database, then I have to edit all routing declarations manually.

Comment: It's the other way around... You build your URL with variables.
For example, within the twig view which will point toward your URL in your code example, you will build your URL like this `<a href="{{ path('route_name', { '_locale'; locale, 'year': acticle.year, 'slug': article.slug, '_format': format }) }}"></a>`. You get the parameters in twig from your controller. Thus, it's in the controller that renderthe current view that you must fetch the required parameters... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parmaters from `parameters.yml` or`config.yml` see [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/routing/service_container_parameters.html)

```
# app/config/routing.yml
contact:
    path:     /{_locale}/contact
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Main:contact }
    requirements:
        _locale: '%app.locales%'


# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    app.locales: en|es
```